# Spring JDBC Injecting DataSource into another bean

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am new to Spring. While learning it, I decided to play around with JDBC.

Cutting short, I have two classes:

Class 1 contains this:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
public class class1 extends class2 {

    private Connection con;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        dataSource = ds;
    }

public void getConnection(){
login(username,password,url);
con = dataSource.getConnection();
}
}
```

Class 1 is basically where I ask user to enter the username/password/ur and then call the method from class2 passing these details. I want to inject value of DataSource from this class to class1. So far this is my code for class2:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

abstract class class2{
public void login(String username, String password, String url){
GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
            DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory();

            BeanDefinitionBuilder bean1 = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                    .rootBeanDefinition("org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource");
            bean1.addPropertyReference("driverClassName", "dataSource");
            bean1.addPropertyValue("driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            bean1.addPropertyReference("url", "dataSource");
            bean1.addPropertyValue("url", "url");
            bean1.addPropertyReference("username", "dataSource");
            bean1.addPropertyValue("username", username);
            bean1.addPropertyReference("password", "dataSource");
            bean1.addPropertyValue("password", password);
            bean1.registerBeanDefinition("dataSource", bean1.getBeanDefinition());

            BeanDefinitionBuilder bean2 = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("class2");
            bean2.addPropertyValue("dataSource", "getCon");
            context.refresh();
            bean2.addPropertyValue("dataSource", new RuntimeBeanReference("dataSource"));

            factory.registerBeanDefinition("getCon", bean2.getBeanDefinition());

}
}
```

However, when I try to execute the method `getConnection()` from class1, it gives NPE. Can anyone tell me correct way to do this?

Also, I want to do this task programmically (not by using xml).

Comment: If you want to do this `The Spring Way` you need to `read the docs`. However, since you stated your new to Spring, I *highly* recommend starting out with [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: Uhhh. I have been using Spring for a while, but those classes made me doubt my level of knowledge on the topic.

Comment: Regarding the advice on Spring Boot: I would not advice somebody to start with that without understanding at least the basic concepts of DI. Starting on the "top" is what makes people think that it is pure magic under the hood.

Comment: Show us the NPE and tell in which line it happens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in Spring then you need to declare a bean definition in application context xml for creating data source and inject to you class.

Alternatively, you can create data source using spring jdbc. Check out this link:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/create-data-source-for-jdbctemplate/